# How can i create a new df column based on matches between a dictionary and another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

I have 2 tables:

**table 1**

```
                          code_count
Year    Month Day   Hour    
2018    10    15    23    {'UNI017SOLC': 138}
              14    23    {'UNI017SOLC': 98}
2017     6    15    10    {'ENE001SOLC': 71}
                    13    {'ENE001SOLC': 68}
                     9    {'ENE001SOLC': 64}
2018    10    14    22    {'UNI017SOLC': 62}
              16     0    {'UNI017SOLC': 51, 'OCU039SOLC': 3}
              19     9    {'UNI017SOLC': 49, 'TRA008AUTO': 4}
2017    6     15    12    {'ENE001SOLC': 45}
2018    10    16     9    {'UNI017SOLC': 35}
```

**table 2**

```
    ID mod                    mod_name  
0   UNI017SOLC                name 4    
1   ENT003INSC                name 54   
2   ENT003OGOV                name 52   
3   OPO021SOLC               name 253   
4   JUS007SOLC               name 116   
5   MOS001SOLC                name 30   
6   UNI016SOLC                name  3   
7   BOM002SOLC                name 27   
8   FAM006                    name  1   
9   AQU001SOLC                name 80
```

What i need to do is to create a new column which has the values of the `mod_name` column if the keys on the `code_count` column on table one matches the the `ID mod` values on table 2. This column should also contain a list with the `mod_names` corresponding to each matching pair of `code_count` key and `ID mod` value across both tables.

The expected output should be something like this:

```
                                   code_count
    Year    Month Day   Hour                                        new_col
    2018    10    15    23    {'UNI017SOLC': 138}                   [name 4]
                  14    23    {'UNI017SOLC': 98}                    [name 4]
    2017     6    15    10    {'ENT003INSC': 71}                    [name 54]
                        13    {'ENT003INSC': 68}                    [name 54]
                         9    {'ENT003INSC': 64}                    [name 54]
    2018    10    14    22    {'UNI017SOLC': 62}                    [name 4]
                  16     0    {'UNI017SOLC': 51, 'BOM002SOLC': 3}   [name 4, name 27]
                  19     9    {'UNI017SOLC': 49, 'JUS007SOLC': 4}   [name 4, name 116] 
    2017    6     15    12    {'ENT003OGOV': 45}                    [name 52
    2018    10    16     9    {'UNI017SOLC': 35}                    [name 4]
```

How could i get this done?? Any help will be much appreciated. Feel free to ask any questions

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert `table 2` to a `dict` then use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with a lambda function using `dict.get`:

```
d = df2.set_index('ID mod')['mod_name'].to_dict()

df['new_col'] = df.code_count.apply(lambda x: [d.get(k) for k in x.keys()])
```

[out]

```
                                              code_count             new_col
Year Month Day Hour                                                         
2018 10    15  23                    {'UNI017SOLC': 138}            [name 4]
           14  23                     {'UNI017SOLC': 98}            [name 4]
2017 6     15  10                     {'ENT003INSC': 71}           [name 54]
               13                     {'ENT003INSC': 68}           [name 54]
               9                      {'ENT003INSC': 64}           [name 54]
2018 10    14  22                     {'UNI017SOLC': 62}            [name 4]
           16  0     {'UNI017SOLC': 51, 'BOM002SOLC': 3}   [name 4, name 27]
           19  9     {'UNI017SOLC': 49, 'JUS007SOLC': 4}  [name 4, name 116]
2017 6     15  12                     {'ENT003OGOV': 45}           [name 52]
2018 10    16  9                      {'UNI017SOLC': 35}            [name 4]
```

Comment: Thank you @Chris A. Your code seems to do the job but i don't understand why am i getting `None` all over. It shouldn't be like that. I know this is a sample table but in my original df every `ID mod` has a matching name. It's impossible to get a`None` value

Comment: Your table 1 is different from your `input` vs `expected output` I've updated using the values of `code_count` from your output - `None` just means the key doesnt exist in table 2

Comment: Allright, i'll check it out and i'll accept if the answer is ok. Thank you!! 

Comment: Hi Chris, i validated your answer. Everything was fine during the final testing of this piece of code. Again, thank you very much for your help, i really appreciate it :)